# Contact form 7 data to 3rd party REST API service - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, api, contact-form-7

I am trying to send word-press contact form 7 data to a 3rd party CRM using their API. I have tried a plug-in called **contact form 7 to API** but to no avail. It is not showing me input type name at all. All fields are blank..
image for reference:
 [blank fields showing in dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkKHS.png)

Please tell me how to correct this or any other way or any reference for same.

Comment: try to use method GET not POST

Comment: Tried, that also not working

Comment: which crm you are want to send the data ?

Comment: why you are not trying to do this by custom way there is couple of hook which can give you the filled data and than from there you can sent the data to the API

Comment: @AzadAlam where did you use TOKEN ?

Answer (score 2):

Try below code here i assuming that you are having first name and last name as a field and their form name is first-name and last-name respectively.

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_mail_sent', 'your_wpcf7_mail_sent_function' ); 

function your_wpcf7_mail_sent_function( $contact_form ) {
 $title = $contact_form->title;
 $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

 if ( $submission ) {
    $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
 }
 $firstName = $posted_data['first-name'];
 $lastName = $posted_data['last-name'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Aki.. Actually I am new to word-press so where I need to use this code, or where to put this code

Comment: In your active theme's functions.php must have this code.